# Is it advantageous if the conflict resolution for a 3d game is fake?

Tags: 3d, physics-engine

The game is you are a monster trainer in "3D" (I am going with WildPet(WP) for the game and the monsters). In battle with one other WP, you give the WildPets commands which can be tactical like hit a box with fire attack) and one the WP may not follow the command and two the attack may miss. I am thinking to simplify the game with simple far or close distance. I am thinking that the commands could simply resolved in the background as math equation with combined text and visual description of the resolution. You have a Firemon versus a Rockmon in a battlefield with boxes near the Rockmon. You give a direct fireblast toward boxes command and it does maths ie. Is (chance of following command) times (chance of fireblast hitting) greater than 0.5 then it hits and arbitrary animation occurs to show the result and damage. I would think this more advantageous than the complicated process of programming a sophisticated physics engine to handle all sorts of scenarios but is it?

Comment: I think that is more the norm. If you want to have physic based attacks, it falls into the action rpg group, which is normally not round based (first title like that in mind is Vindictus).

Comment: This looks like a judgement call you'll need to make. There are monster training games that use simple formulas to calculate outcomes (eg. most Pokémon battles), and there are monster training games that do include some degree of iterative simulation (eg. throwing a Pokéball in GO, or some of the open world content in Legends Arceus). These both work, and have different impacts on how the game plays. The choice of which style of play you prefer for your game is yours to make. It's not clear to me what you need from us Internet strangers here.

Comment: Is it advantageous from the point of overall game creation complexity and processing power?

Comment: More in terms of user enjoyment. If you know you can aim well and still miss 50% of the time because the item says so, what good is the aiming system in the game? If you want the user to actively engage, it is the way to go. Processing power for a simple curve/ throw/ hit detection is nothing

Comment: You can't aim, you can only direct. You hit more if you train your pet well. Clever attacks pay off but are high risk of failure. Simple attacks from well trained pets hit nearly 100% of the time but may do little damage. What is the processing power of simulating burning, boiling, electrical interference?

Comment: "What is the processing power of simulating [literally ANY mechanic you'd use in a Pokémon-like]?" - still nothing. You're worrying about the wrong problem. Design for the player experience and game feel you want. Modern devices will handle it just fine. if you implement your feature and notice a performance problem, post here to show your implementation and ask how to solve that specific problem.